# Trying do understand this DAC problem

Tags: dac

So here is the question :

[image]

Here is the solution:

[image]

I dont understand the origin of the parasitic capacitances and their effect (marked with (1)). Some books mentioned that the delay through the switch network is a major limitation on speed other sources say parasitic tail capacitances appear at the current source transistor, charging and discharging of Ctail will limit the speed of the converter.

So do these capacitances appear at each mirrored transistor or they appear because of the switches, or both? I took a note where those capacitances depend on the VDS of the transistors, that i dont know why. I also presume that Cout is the effect of all these capacitances in the output?

[image]

Above is continuation of the solution, i dont understand why this circuit needs to have its output sampled at a given frequency, i assume that Ts = 1/Fs, what's the need for that?

In (3), when using the settling error to find Rout i think something is missing in the exponencial with -Ts/Rout. The time constant is generally given by R*C but in this situation i am not sure, should C just be Cout(effect of all these capacitances in the output)?

Below is the solution for c)
[image]

The straight line coming from the origin is the ideal transfer curve, the top line is the output of the circuit if all transistors had a current mismatch error of +1% and the bottom line is the output of the circuit if all transistors had a current mismath error of -1%. There's a special case that occurs during the transition from code 127 to code 128 (01111111 to 10000000), in code 127 if all those 1's have a current mismatch from Iref of +1% and if in code 128 that single 1 bit leads to a current mismatch of -1% where gonna have that step during the transition of those codes.

While computing that error we get to (4), my confusion here is saying that the total variance is equal to 255*deviation /Iref, the variance is the square of the deviation so how is that equal?

My next question is in (5) where this proprety was used:

[image]

How can i used that equation if the expression i have in (4) isnt equal to the one shown above? I dont have Iref squared

My last question is what does any of this as to do with the the question c) ?

"The minimum value for the (W.L) value in order to have a manufacturing
yield of at least 99.97% for a matching at 8 bit level. "

What does manufacturing yield of at least 99.97% for a matching at 8 bit level mean here?

Comment: The output is not “sampled” at a given frequency. The output is *updated* at that frequency. DACs have a specified output update rate, usually just called sample rate, since that’s the sample rate of the time-discrete signal fed to the DAC’s inputs.

Comment: Too many questions to address at once and can't interpret your notes. But if it helps, every transistor has drain gate capacitance proportional to area (WL). So that along with any load capacitance will be Cout per side. Ts is width of held signal (or half the update rate) each sample. BTW. What text is that?

Comment: @pat class sides